# Modifying table entries from LibreOffice Base, possible?

Tags: mysql, libreoffice, libreoffice-base

I've successfully connected LibreOffice Base with MySQL data base server. I've tested if I modify my table from host (free hosting service on internet) then the changes are reflected when refreshing the table object in LO Base.
But my question is, can I modify DB table directly from LO Base? I guess that it's possible using sql queries from LO Base, but how? Please give me some insights or tutorials. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The normal way to alter a table:

1. Tools -> SQL
2. Enter an `ALTER TABLE` command and press `Execute` button.

A way that works, even though it complains that no result set is returned:

1. Create a query in SQL view.
2. Enter `ALTER TABLE` command.
3. Click button in toolbar to mark it as `Run SQL command directly`.  Or Edit -> `Run SQL command directly`.
4. Close the query and double-click to run it.

My guess is it could be done with a macro as well, similar to https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=75763 but using `ALTER TABLE`.

For more ideas see https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=61&t=37687.

**EDIT:**

Inserting new row data in a form is easier than altering the table.  First, make sure this works:

1. Double-click on your table under `Tables`.
2. Insert -> Record, or enter data in the last new row.

If Insert -> Record is disabled, then you need to set up the table for editing.  Make sure that your connection to the database allows editing.  Also the table must have a primary key.

Once you can insert records in Table view, it's time to create the form:

1. Under `Forms`, `Use Wizard to Create Form`.
2. Select your table and press `>>` to include all fields.
3. Click `Finish`.

Now you should be able to open the form and enter data into the final new row.

More complete instructions with examples are at http://www.open-of-course.org/courses/mod/url/view.php?id=786.

Comment: I was successful in entering new row data in my remote table, using method 1 you suggested. Now I am trying to do that using forms in LO Base. It is intended to be used by my colleagues in updating their pupil qualification tables. Please, give a nice insight :-) in this matter.