# How to create an update query with Open Office Base?

Tags: openoffice.org, openoffice-base

I want to create basically an update query on Open Office Base (the same way with Ms ACCESS).

Answer (score 4):

Base does not typically use [update queries](https://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/query/snytax/update-query.html) (but see below).  Instead, the easiest way to do an update command is to go to Tools -> SQL.  Enter something similar to the following, then press `Execute`:

```sql
UPDATE "Table1" SET "Value" = 'BBB' WHERE ID = 0
```

The other way is to run the command with a macro.  Here is an example using Basic:

```vb
Sub UpdateSQL
    REM Run an SQL command on a table in LibreOffice Base
    Context = CreateUnoService("com.sun.star.sdb.DatabaseContext")
    databaseURLOrRegisteredName = "file:///C:/Users/JimStandard/Desktop/New Database.odb"
    Db = Context.getByName(databaseURLOrRegisteredName )
    Conn = Db.getConnection("","") 'username & password pair - HSQL default blank

    Stmt = Conn.createStatement()
    'strSQL = "INSERT INTO ""Table1"" (ID,""Value"") VALUES (3,'DDD')"
    strSQL = "UPDATE ""Table1"" SET ""Value"" = 'CCC' WHERE ID = 0"
    Stmt.executeUpdate(strSQL)

    Conn.close()
End Sub
```

Note that the data can also be modified with a form or by editing the table directly.

Under some circumstances it *is* possible to create an update query.  I couldn't get this to work with the default built-in HSQLDB 1.8 engine, but it worked with MYSQL.

1. In the Queries section, `Create Query in SQL View`
2. Click the toolbar button to `Run SQL Command directly`.
3. Enter a command like the following:

```sql
    update mytable set mycolumn = 'This is some text.' where ID = 59;
```

4. Hit <kbd>F5</kbd> to run the query.

It gives an error that `The data content could not be loaded`, but it still performs the update and changes the data.  To get rid of the error, the command needs to [return a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446073/get-updated-value-in-mysql-instead-of-affected-rows).  For example, I created this stored procedure in MYSQL:

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE update_val
(
   IN id_in INT,
   IN newval_in VARCHAR(100)
)
BEGIN
    UPDATE test_table SET value = newval_in WHERE id = id_in;
    SELECT id, value FROM test_table WHERE id = id_in;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then this query in LibreOffice Base modifies the data without giving any errors:

```sql
CALL update_val(2,'HHH')
```

See also:

- https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=75763
- https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=61&t=6655
- https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/32700/how-to-create-an-update-query-in-base-sql/
- [Modifying table entries from LibreOffice Base, possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704631/modifying-table-entries-from-libreoffice-base-possible/33716340#33716340)

Comment: That Work, thank you very much for the time spent on my question