# Error message when running UPDATE command in SQL

Tags: sql-update, libreoffice-base

I am trying to run the UPDATE command in SQL to change the values of certain columns based on a specified ID.

```
UPDATE Table
SET variable1=300,variable2=600
WHERE ID=platinum;
```

However, whenever I try to run the query (I am using Libreoffice Base), I get the following error message:

```
The given command is not a SELECT statement. Only queries are allowed.
```

I am encountering this problem whenever I try to run a query which does not have a SELECT command. Can anyone provide any input?

Comment: It will be related to how/where you execute that SQL. How/where do you execute that SQL?

Comment: What tool/version of SQL are you using?  It sounds like it only wants you reading and not writing.

Comment: I have no experience in Libreoffice Base, but hopefully this helps you out: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/32700/how-to-create-an-update-query-in-base-sql/

Comment: I am using Libreoffice Base where both the table is contained, and to execute the query.

Comment: While we're on the topic, what's the best (or standard) environment that professionals use to run SQL queries?

Comment: If `platinum` is a literal value, then you must wrap it in single quotes. This might not resolve the issue, but it still is necessary.

Comment: *"what's the best environment"*: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: What is `platinum` -- a literal value, a variable, or a column from another table?

Comment: "platinum" is a set of characters - data type CHAR

Answer (score 1):

In LO Base, there are two main ways to run an UPDATE command: `Tools -> SQL` or create a macro.

For examples and details, see [How to create an update query with Open Office Base?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34560212/how-to-create-an-update-query-with-open-office-base/34562420#34562420)