# Execute SQL query from OpenOffice macro

Tags: sql, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc, openoffice-base

I have an SQL query which I want to run when a button in my OpenOffice Calc worksheet is pressed. I've found out how to bind a macro to the button, but I can't get a connection to the database it seems (I've created an .odb file and I can run the query from within OpenOffice Base).

How do I tell OpenOffice Calc which connection to use and which query to execute?

Comment: What code did you try for connecting to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a connection to the .odb file as in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34562420/5100564).

Then perform a query using `executeQuery()` and `getString()` as shown here: https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide/Database_Access