# Possible to change PostgreSQL table design using LibreOffice Base?

Tags: postgresql, libreoffice-base

I read that LibreOffice Base has a native Postgres driver, so I thought that might be a good way to play around with the database structure, creating new tables, altering and dropping existing ones etc.

Almost everything seems to work fine. I can connect to the DB and open and edit all tables, create new ones, delete existing ones. I can basically do everything, except change the data definition of existing columns. So, I could delete the column entirely, and I can easily create new columns in the same table. But once they're there, I cannot change them anymore, the respective options are greyed out in Base.

Could this be a bug or am I missing something else?

Comment: I would not expect a high level DBMS independent tool like LibreOffice to be able to alter/change the structure of tables for all databases it supports connecting to. So I guess this is just a matter of "not implemented".

Comment: You're probably right. I just tried connecting MS Access to it using ODBC and it behaves even worse. But pgadmin is pretty good actually, will just stick to using it instead - at least for the data definition. To work with the actual data, Base seems to be not such a bad choice, though.

Comment: To clarify: [pgAdmin](http://pgadmin.org/) is a [GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface) app for administering a Postgres cluster (collection of databases). The pgAdmin app is open-source and free-of-cost. You can use other tools instead, but pgAdmin is a good start for beginners. Handy for pros too, as it often comes bundled with Postgres installations. You can define your tables and columns as well as query and view data.

Comment: Hi Basil, since you consider pgadmin mostly "a good start for beginners", I'm curious as to what other, more advanced or simply better tools you use to administer Postgres?

Comment: You can also copy and paste a table, and in the dialog that pops up there is an option to change the column definitions.  Possibly you could make a copy of the table with your changes and then delete the old table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In LO Base, it is not possible to modify existing columns using the graphical tools.

Instead, go to `Tools` -> `SQL` in the main menu bar.  This will show a dialog where you can enter an `ALTER TABLE` command.  For example (from the [postgres docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-altertable.html)):

```
ALTER TABLE distributors RENAME COLUMN address TO city;
```

See also [Modifying table entries from LibreOffice Base, possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704631/modifying-table-entries-from-libreoffice-base-possible)

Comment: No quite true. When using embedded HSQLDB it is possible to alter column types.