# LibreOffice Base: open context menu to edit order of columns in a table control

Tags: windows-10, windows-7-x64, libreoffice-base

I have a table control.
I want to edit the order columns.
I right-click on the column header, but the context menu that opens, is the one of the table control itself, but the one for the columns.

I also tried already:

- Keyboard-only edit mode (Enter, Shift-F10): displays only one single entry in the context menu: Add Column. And this only on Windows 7. On Windows 10, the audio loudness box opens instead.
- Keyboard-only edit mode (Enter, Shift-Space): nothing happens at all

What do I wrong... or is it a bug or an incompatibility?
I use the LibreOffice 5.0.4.2 on Win7 and on Win10.

Thanks a lot in advance for your comments!

Answer (score 0):

To move a column in a table control:

1. In the Forms section of LO Base, right-click the form that has the table control and choose Edit.
2. **Left**-click and drag the column to a new location.  It will create a copy of the column.
3. Right-click on the column in the old location and choose Delete Column.

Note that this only modifies the table control in the form, not the underlying table.  To modify the underlying table, see [Possible to change PostgreSQL table design using LibreOffice Base?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34861831/possible-to-change-postgresql-table-design-using-libreoffice-base)

Comment: Thanks.

But when I left-click the column, there's always the whole table control selected.
I can't make it to select only the column.

This means: When trying to drag the column, I always move the whole table control.
So, how can I select only a column?

Comment: Are you clicking the title of the column?  Clicking where the data is displayed will select the entire table.  If you get the click-area right, the title of that column will be highlighted.

Comment: Yes, I click the column title, but still the whole table control is selected.

Comment: @mickey Maybe the table is grouped with another control (such as a label) so it won't let you select inside the group?  You can test for this by right-clicking and seeing if Group→Ungroup is clickable.  My next test would be to see if you can move the file to a different setup (such as a different machine or different version of LibreOffice) and seeing if the problem persists in the other setup.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem with the exact same versions of LibreOffice and Windows. But the problem does not happen anymore with the newer version of LibreOffice -- 5.1.0.3 -- which I downloaded today.

Although I couldn't find a reference to this problem in the Release Notes page for LibreOffice v. 5.1 (https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/ReleaseNotes/5.1), it seems it was a bug that was fixed.